# Is it possible to declare a constant based on a preexisting variable's value in VBA?

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, constants

I need to create a multidimensional array, but I do not know the height of the array.
I get this value and store it in a variable. Unfortunately I cannot use a variable when declaring the array, I need to use constants. So I thought that I could just declare a constant from the variable, but then I get the same error "Constant Expression Required" just on an earlier line.

```
lr = Tables.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Const constlr As Integer = lr

Dim TableNamesArr(2 To constlr, 1 To 4) As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 2 To lr
    For j = 1 To 4
        TableNamesArr(i, j) = Tables.Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

Currently line 3 is the issue - 
Const constlr As Integer = lr

but if I remove that line and change all constlr to lr, then it is line 5 - 
`Dim TableNamesArr(2 To lr, 1 To 4) As String`.

The lr is the problem, it needs to be an integer or constant, but not a variable holding an integer

The code works fine if I change:

```
Const constlr As Integer = lr
```

to

```
Const constlr As Integer = 102
```

Comment: which line of your code causes error?

Comment: Currently 3 - Const constlr As Integer = lr

but if I remove that line and change all constlr to lr, then it is line 5 - 
Dim TableNamesArr(2 To lr, 1 To 4) As String. The lr is the problem, it needs to be an integer or constant, but not a variable holding an integer

Comment: The answer to you main (title) question is **No, you can not do this** and the proof is in your question and your tests (last few lines). My question is- why do you think you have to have `lr` set as constant? Think of constant definition- it is something you don't change but you want to change it. It doesn't make sens.

Comment: I don't want to change it, but I don't know what its value will be; VBA figures this out.  So the question is, how can I retrieve that value from the variable and put it into the constant. This only happens once, the value does not change.

Comment: So, once again, you can not do it by code but type it manually as you do. Again, constant is something fixed and should not be set based on variable. Use variable instead.

Comment: :( oh well. Thanks for the help. Turns out my logic was bad anyways. I completed my original idea by just sticking to cell references and avoiding the array altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable in Redim, not in Dim. You actually don't need the constant for this.

```
lr = Tables.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Const constlr As Integer = lr
Dim TableNamesArr() As String
Redim TableNamesArr(2 To constlr, 1 To 4)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 2 To lr
    For j = 1 To 4
        TableNamesArr(i, j) = Tables.Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read values from Range without looping, in a simple way:

```
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = Range("a1:a5").Value
```

Instead of Range("a1:a5") you may reference your range by selection or other methods `Selection.Value` or `Activesheet.UsedRange.Value`.

If your range is in a table you may try this code stolen from [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables):

```
Sub MultiColumnTable_To_Array()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim x As Long

'Set path for Table variable
  Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

'Create Array List from Table
  myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange

'Loop through each item in Third Column of Table (displayed in Immediate Window [ctrl + g])
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Debug.Print myArray(x, 3)
  Next x

End Sub
```